# Linq to SQL - Group By Table

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, group-by

This doesn't work:

```
Dim Qry = From RE In DB.Res_Estab Where _
(RE.Estab_Code = Estab_Code) Group By RE.Research Into Group Select Research
```

Because Research is a table, not a value. It renders the error "A group by expression can only contain non-constant scalars that are comparable by the server."

So I'm splitting in two queries:

```
Dim Qry = From RE In DB.Res_Estab Where _
(RE.Estab_Code = Estab_Code) Group By RE.Res_Code Into Group Select Res_Code

Dim Qry2 = From R In DB.Research Where Qry.Contains(R.Res_Code) Order By R.Descr
```

Which works, but seems redundant. Is there a way of doing this in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the answer [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/converting-sql-to-linq-part-5-group-by-and-having-bill-horst/) -

```
From RE In DB.Res_Estab _
Group By RE.Research 
Into Group
Where RE.Estab_Code = Estab_Code
Select Research
```

Comment: Doesn't work. RE is not accessible after Group, otherwise it would render the same error "A group by expression can only contain non-constant scalars that are comparable by the server."

Comment: I really dont have vb to test the syntax..but if you check out the link which I have provided you should be able to write one single group by query...and call it something else than INTO `Group` say like INTO `Total`